# extracting paragraph before each html table using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, paragraph

I have a requirement where i have to extract paragraph just before each table along with the table content form a website.

i am able to extract table data using jsoup easily but not able to extract paragraph that is occuring exactly before a table.
i tried following things:-

```
1. doc.select("p") but its giving extra values because some text in table columns are also in <p> tag.
2. getElementsByTag  but no luck.
```

sample table:

```
<p>
<a id="table heading" name="table name"></a>
<b>Sports equipments</b>
</p>
 <table width="98%" cellpadding="0" border="1">
 <tbody>
 <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffcc" align="left">
<th width="25%" scope="col">Company</th>
<th width="25%" scope="col">Product</th>
<th width="20%" scope="col">Availability</th>
<th width="55%" scope="col">Related Information</th>
 <th width="20%" scope="col">
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" valign="top" rowspan="2">
<div>
Nike
<br>
1-800-545-8800
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</td>
<td width="10%" valign="top">
<div>sports kit</div>
</td>
<td width="15%" valign="top" rowspan="2">
<div>Available</div>
</td>
<td width="24%" valign="top" rowspan="2">
<div>Product is available and shipping.</div>
</td>
<td width="16%" valign="top" rowspan="2">Demand increase.</td>
<td width="12%" valign="top" rowspan="2">
<div>
<div>3/26/2014</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i have to extract:

```
<b>Sports equipments</b>
```

along with the table content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your selector to this: `"p > b"`.

Since i don't have your full html, it's hard to say if it will work there, but for your example it does:

```
    final String html = ... // the html of your example
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    /*
     * Selects b-tags, that are direct childs of p-tags.
     */
    for( Element element : doc.select("p > b") )
    {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
```

This prints:

```
<b>Sports equipments</b>
```

Comment: thanks,its working and i also found one alternative way

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();  
    Elements table = doc.select("table”);  
    for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {  
    Element tablevalue = table.get(i);  
    Element para = tablevalue.previousElementSibling();  
   System.out.println(para.text());  
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
Elements table = doc.select("table”);
for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
  Element tablevalue = table.get(i);
  Element para = tablevalue.previousElementSibling();
  System.out.println(para.text());
}
```